# Grails using OpenID4Java causes SSLPeerUnverifiedException

Tags: grails, ssl, openid

I have a grails application that attempts to use OpenID4Java to authenticate with our own OpenID provider.

The certificate our provider presents is from RapidSSL has been signed by GeoTrust Global.

Browsers accept the certificate automatically.

I'm on a Mac and attempting to add the GeoTrustGlobalCA to cacerts at `/Library/Java/Home/lib/security/cacerts` results in the prompt `Certificate already exists in keystore under alias <keychainrootca-132>` I added it again anyway.

Starting grails within STS with `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl run-app -https`

I can find the following in the output;

```
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=GeoTrust Global CA, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US
  Issuer:  CN=GeoTrust Global CA, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x23456
  Valid from Tue May 21 14:00:00 EST 2002 until Sat May 21 14:00:00 EST 2022

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=GeoTrust Primary Certification Authority, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US
  Issuer:  CN=GeoTrust Primary Certification Authority, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x18acb56afd69b6153a636cafdafac4a1
  Valid from Mon Nov 27 11:00:00 EST 2006 until Thu Jul 17 09:59:59 EST 2036
```

However attempting to access the service from the application results in;

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
  at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:352)
  at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128)
  at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:339)
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:123)
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:147)
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:101)
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:381)
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:641)
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:576)
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:554)
  at org.openid4java.util.HttpCache.head(HttpCache.java:335)
  at org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisResolver.retrieveXrdsLocation(YadisResolver.java:400)
  at org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisResolver.discover(YadisResolver.java:248)
  at org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisResolver.discover(YadisResolver.java:232)
  at org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisResolver.discover(YadisResolver.java:166)
  at org.openid4java.discovery.Discovery.discover(Discovery.java:147)
  at org.openid4java.discovery.Discovery.discover(Discovery.java:129)
  at org.openid4java.consumer.ConsumerManager.discover(ConsumerManager.java:542)
  at org.openid4java.consumer.ConsumerManager$discover.call(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We resolved the issue with an additional Apache directive along the lines of

`SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/intermediate.crt`

It seems that we needed an intermediate CA entry because of who our issuer was.

Answer (score 0):

I resoved the problem by bypassing the certificate check.
When you new a ConsumerManager object, do not use the default Constructor.
sample code is here:

```
private ConsumerManager getFreeHttpsManager() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
    //ignore all
    TrustManager trm = new X509TrustManager() {
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }

        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {

        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
        }
    };

    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sc.init(null, new TrustManager[]{trm}, null);
    //  HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
    X509HostnameVerifier verifier = new X509HostnameVerifier() {

        @Override
        public void verify(String string, SSLSocket ssls) throws IOException {
        }

        @Override
        public void verify(String string, X509Certificate xc) throws SSLException {
        }

        @Override
        public void verify(String string, String[] strings, String[] strings1) throws SSLException {
        }

        @Override
        public boolean verify(String string, SSLSession ssls) {
            return true;
        }
    };
    Discovery discovery = new Discovery();
    discovery.setYadisResolver(new YadisResolver(new HttpFetcherFactory(sc, verifier)));
    return new ConsumerManager(
            new RealmVerifierFactory(new YadisResolver(new HttpFetcherFactory(sc, verifier))),
            discovery,  // uses HttpCache internally
            new HttpFetcherFactory(sc, verifier));
}
```